# Can't automatically choose google account during login Auth0 Ionic3 Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic3, auth0

I'm working with Auth0 to perform sign in with Google.

There is one problem. If I have two google accounts, everything is OK. I can choose one of them and log in.
But if I have less than two, I can't. I don't see any choose account page. This step is always skipped and browser freezes after. Browser doesn't close. I should close it manually and of course I'm not authorized after.

Did anybody face with such problem? 
It's present on IOS and Android 5 and less. 
If we are talking about Android, I found the solution.
I append `clearcache=yes` and `clearsessioncache=yes` to `var tab = browser.open(url, '_blank');` in auth0 library code. But it doesn't solve the problem with IOS, because IOS is using SafariViewController instead of InAppBrowser.